# Rails Join Table with Model Assoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, join

I have a model that relies on associations of two other models like so:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :vendor_id, :price, :upc
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

My question is this: if I have these associations in the join model, do I need to specify these associations again in the migration to create the inventory_items table so that in includes attributes from :items and :vendor? Here is the current migration (hasn't run yet) to create that table:

```
class CreateInventoryItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :inventory_items do |t|
      t.integer :upc
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :vendor_id
    end
  end
end
```

Browsing the sqlit3 db leads me to believe that I do need to do that somehow. Best way to do that? I'm newish to RoR, so any feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your models need to know about all associations, but your migrations don't care about associations. So long as you have foreign keys in your child model, that's all you need in a migration to properly set up your associations on the database level.

With Rails, the idea is to do as little as possible on a database level, and as much as possible on the application ([ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194915/what-is-orm-as-related-to-ruby-on-rails)) level. Therefore, you let models know about the associations, which will enable them to use the according ORM methods to handle the associations, but your database doesn't need to know about associations.

Comment: Thanks, that mostly makes sense. So will attributes from :vendor and :item then be reflected in my join table 'inventory_items' even without specifying the associations in the migration? Perhaps a better question is this: Is it necessary to have attributes of :vendor and :item reflected in the join table 'inventory_items' in order to access them in my app?

Comment: For belongs_to associations, you need the foreign key, such as `vendor_id`. Apart from that, just set the associations in your model, that's enough. Then you will be able to do stuff like `InventoryItem.items.first` and `InventoryItem.first.vendor`. Your migration above should work fine.